# Help for implementing the maintenance of the connected components in the Euclidean plane in logarithmic time

Tags: graphs, computational-geometry

I am aware of a logarithmic-time algorithm to maintain the connected components of graphs in the Euclidean plane [(D. Eppstein, GF Italiano, R. Tamassia, RE Tarjan, J. Westbrook, and M. Yung. Maintenance of a minimum spanning forest in a dynamic plane graph. *J. Algorithms*, 13 (1): 33 {54, 1992.).](http://web.cs.swarthmore.edu/~adanner/cs97/s08/pdf/eppstein92maintenance.pdf)

Does anyone know if there is an implementation of this work or if there are other results that are easier to implement?